TYPO3 v11 / Custom backend module: generate link to edit a record with permission problems?
TYPO3 v11
In my extension there is a module to edit records in the custom tables. Now I try to use the record edit mechanism of the list module. In the Fluid template of the module I use the <f:be.link /> viewHelper:
<f:be.link route="record_edit" parameters="{id: 12316, edit: {tx_mydata_domain_model_campaign: {campaign: campaign.uid} } }">
    edit
</f:be.link>

This leads to an error message:

The edit form could not be loaded for the requested records. This
might be due to insufficient permissions.

Which is not true as I am admin and can easily access these records in the list module.
What is missing here?

The link has to take the following form:
https://my.website.com/typo3/record/edit?edit[tx_mydata_domain_model_campaign][51]=edit&id=12316
where '51' is the campaign uid which has to be part of the array key.
In my use case I render a list of links. Thus the campaign uid is variable in a <f:for> loop. This seems not to be possible to be generated only with Fluid. The parameters array must be prepared in the controller action. Then it is simple to render it in Fluid:
<f:be.link route="record_edit" parameters="{id: 12316, edit: {editParam}">
    edit
</f:be.link>

